# Will Firebase provide tests for other OS and does it support manual testing?

Tags: android, iphone, firebase, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

I have seen that firebase provides testlabs that can test only Android devices. I want to know if Firebase will also support other OS(Windows, Blackberry, IOS) testing ? Also if Fire base will provide manual testing to test the apps directly by using touch movements ?(Is this possible in an emulator ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Test Lab for Android is (as its name implies) only available for Android. There is no support for other operating systems at the moment.

Since the tests are run in a remote lab, you cannot really *manually* run those tests. But what you *can* do manually is [record a test in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html). This feature was added in Android Studio 2.2 and allow you to record a Espresso test, simply by using your application. You can then [run this Espresso test in Firebase Test Lab](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html#run-ctl).